# Having trouble with macOS specific config of MYSQL in Node.js when running on Windows

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, config

I'm in a bootcamp and we're in the middle of a group project, im getting an error:

```
connect ENOENT /tmp/mysql.sock
```

It is caused by the following code:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
require("dotenv").config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql",
    port: 3306,
    dialectOptions: {
      socketPath: "/tmp/mysql.sock",
    },
  },
);

module.exports = sequelize;
```

My instructor told us that the following part is for macOS users, and I'm on Windows:

```
dialectOptions: {
  socketPath: "/tmp/mysql.sock",
}
```

Is there a way to write this so these lines are ignores if you're on Windows but they are run if you're on mac?

I've searched the web and haven't really been able to find anything? So I've just been commenting it out locally and its been working, but there's gotta be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the way people solve this is that if code needs to run on multiple environments (like Mac, Windows, or at a hosting providers), they will not add MySQL connection settings to their code, they will add it to a configuration file. So just make it part of your `.env` configuration instead.

That said, you can also connect to MySQL on a mac without the unix socket